# SSIS Lookup behavior is odd

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS lookup that behaves oddly. It matches data just fine in most cases but in many cases provides no match when the data viewer shows that the data matched. The really strange thing is that the lookup connection uses a SQL query with no where clause. If I change the SQL query to include a where clause that returns only rows similar to the one that isn't matching and re-run it; then the data matches.

For example if the SQL query is:

```
Select ColumnA, ColumnB
From TableA
```

ColumnA is the one I'm looking for a match on and ColumnB is the one I want to add to the dataflow.

The query provides results like this

```
AA, B

AC, D

BE, F

BG, H
```

(All the data is all upper case so that is not an issue)

My input column to match is AC but no match is returned (It returns a match for AA and BG). Yet if I change the query to include a where clause like this:
where ColumnA like 'A%' (returning only two rows)

then I get a match.
Has anyone ever seen anything like this before and have a fix?

Comment: Are you trying to match the columns that are equal or those that contain some value? Add a clear sample of both tables

Comment: I can't do a sample; proprietary and private data is involved. The example I've given illustrates the problem. The column from the source is AC and it must match the column from the query which does provide AC. If you've never seen anything like this before then you probably don't have the answer.

Comment: `SELECT RTRIM(ColumnA) AS ColumnA, ColumnB` and also ensure that you have an RTRIM applied to SourceA - do you get matches now?

Comment: How many rows in the table that you are querying in the Lookup?   Are you using cache at all?

Comment: If it isn't a case issue then probably trailing spaces. These are ignored in SQL but significant in SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your example is too simplified.

Using SSIS lookups one has to understand the difference to a database comparison.

SSIS lookups in full cache mode are exclusivly done in memory. This means the comparison is done within the SSIS component not paying any attention to your database collation. Thus one easily has the problem of capitalization you mention in your original post.

There might be subtle differences:

- leading or trailing spaces
- accentuated characters or something else that miht be affected by the collation
- different data types. For example if you do a lookup on numeric datatypes the just match if the have exactly the same datatype. (24.00 does not match 24.0) ...

Hope the solution is one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer though I wanted to comment that all the suggestions about forcing exact matching by removing leading/trailing spaces etc. had already been tried.

What I found was that an unrelated function call would fail for certain data and stop the query but in the lookup it would fail silently and the package would continue to run. I've never seen a query failure not cause a package failure but that happened in this case. So when that would happen data that should have matched would not be added to the lookup cache and no match would be found. When limiting the query with a where clause that would only return similar rows, the failure would not occur and the data would match. That's why the behavior seemed so strange. I don't know why the package would not fail when the query failed. It seems to me that the package should have failed with an error about the query instead of just stopping the query and continuing the package.